# How to trigger controller action by Azure storage queue like in Azure functions?

Tags: .net, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-storage-queues, .net-core-3.1

I am aware that an Azure function app offers a variety of ways its functions can be triggered. Among this is a the Azure storage queue trigger.

I need to use this exact method in my on-premise .NET Core 3.1 Web API project, which until now is exclusively triggered by http requests.

Can this be done?

Cheers

Comment: You *could* have an Azure Function that gets triggered by the Azure Storage Queue trigger, and this Azure Function could then call your on-premise Web API endpoint

Comment: True, although then I have to deal with an on-premise data gateway and firewall configuration, which I wanted to avoid. Should have stated this in my question, sorry.

Comment: I guess one approximation would be to manually check for queue entries every x seconds...

Comment: You can actually run Azure Functions including the triggers on-prem as well, using KEDA: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda

Comment: Thank you. That on the other hand would require docker to be running on the server which is not the case, and tbh I don't think that there ever will. I really had hoped for something I could leverage in an dotnet core app, e.g. with the worker service, or something like that

Comment: Can you modify your question and describe clearly?

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't really tried this out before, I believe you should be able to run the [Azure Functions Host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host) locally similar to how it runs inside its [docker container](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/Dockerfile).

Another option would be to use the [WebJobs SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) (on top of which Azure Functions is built) which you should be able to use (along with all available functions bindings) to create a standalone service that you can run on-premise.

Comment: Running the azure functions host locally - outside a docker container - would be the answer, I guess. Also preferably, since I'm fairly comfortable with functions. But the WebJobs SDK  also seems worth a look.

Comment: It works really good, using that webjobs SDK. Marked it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: I unmarked the proposed answer again. It works locally with dotnet run. But when I want to deploy this and run the compiled content. The logs show error messages referencing C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\StorageAccountProvider.cs: which does not exist on my system. I didn't code it as well. This leads me to believe, this was hardcoded by the SDK, in expectation that the project will run in Azure (App Service), where the host has this file. Whereas I'm trying to run it on-prem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how/where you deployed it?

Comment: A little late I suppose, also the app does not exist anymore. But for sake of clarity, the web API project was deployed into an Azure App Service using the VS tooling. I might need to do this again in the near future and post here if it still does not work as expected.